# Cannot decrypt value for display that was passed through generate_password_hash

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have table in which i have few columns which are as following and EC3 column is encrypted i used encryption which is there for salt password envcrytion
This table have more than one rows and i want to display each and every row in the web page but column which has encrypted filed should be convert back to original when 
displaying on the web page

```
T1
----C1 Varchar(20)
----C2 int
----EC3 varchar(256)
----C4 datetime
```

In My Model class

```
@property
    def ec(self):
        raise AttributeError('ec is not readable attribute')


    @ec.setter
    def ec(self,ec):
        self.ec3 = generate_password_hash(ec)


    def verify_ec(self,ec):
        return check_password_hash(self.ec3,ec)
```

My aim is here to get the records from table and diplay it I am using the Flask and SQL Alchemy to do it. When  i will be display it in the web page EC3 column should be shown as de crypted.Since i am new to SQL Alchemy i am hard to find select single column and even how to view all rows in single query while taking each rows column EC3 should be de crypted.

This is my view decorator

```
@app.route('/listallEC3')
@login_required
def listallEC3():
    decodeEC3 = T1.query.filter_by(u_id = current_user.id).first()

    finalEC3=decodeEC3.verify_ec(decodeEC3)
    return render_template('EC3/viewallEC3.html',finalEC3 = finalEC3)
```

Please help me out to fix this.
Thank you very much for taking your time to answer this.

Comment: I think i have some how got feeling that verify_ec is calling check_password_hash and it will have accepted EC3 values in plain text so that can be verified against hash... so i guess what i am looking for wrong function ideally i should be looking for function which convert hash into plain text is it feasible option if it please guide me how to approach it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.  The *entire point* of hashing is so that someone who sees the database value does not see the real value.  When comparing the hashes, the input value is hashed and the *hashes* are compared, no decryption occurs.  You should *never* store user passwords in a form that is reversible.

Encryption is not the same as hashing.  If you want to encrypt a value and decrypt it later, you'll need to use a different solution.  For example, the [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) package offers the Fernet algorithm for encrypting with a secret key.